# Python unit-test assertions are being joined by newlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

While using `unittest.TestCase.run(test_class(test))`, the correct errors are being reported but they are being joined by `\n`.

```
AssertionError: False is not true : Failures: [],  Errors: [(<module1 testMethod=method1>, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "<file_name>", line 20, in method1\n    \'resource_partitions\')\n  File "error_source_file_path", line 23, in error_function\n    error_line_statement\nKeyError: \'gen_data\'\n')]
```

**How can these be removed and replaced with actual newlines instead?**

Has it got something to do with ***line-endings*** on my machine (currently set to `\n`)

Comment: Have you tried printing this string?

Comment: It's normal, it's the console's way of showing you the newlines so that you can copy-paste them into another variable.

Comment: Not sure why there's so much downvoting. The difference between string literals and their representation, it can be very confusing. This is a legit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an intended behaviour.

The string is being *displayed* as a part an object. Such displays *always* print escape sequences rather to convert them to their specific char.

Look in this short example with string in interpreter:

```
>>> "spam\neggs"
'spam\neggs'
>>> print("spam\neggs")
spam
eggs
```

The first one gets displayed because it's an interactive console, in normal code it would never happen. But that's also how string in other object behave.

Printing list containing a string vs printing each element separately:

```
>>> print(["spam\neggs"])
['spam\neggs']
>>> for element in ["spam\neggs"]: print(element)
... 
spam
eggs
```